# Search a Table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form on my website that I use to send information to a MySQL table, then I have a PHP file called read.php that retrieves the information from the MySQL table and displays it on a page. This works completely fine and I have no issues with it. However I would now like to add a search function so the table can be searched by things such as first name, last name, email etc.

Here is my read.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>messages</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Message Center</h1>

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'removed', 'removed', 'removed');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT*FROM specialisttable");

echo"<table border='1'>
Specialist Table
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Website</th>
<th>Speciality</th>
<th>Street Name</th>
<th>Suburb</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>Post Code</th>
<th>Comments</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['speciality'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['streetname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['suburb'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['postcode'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

}
echo"</table>";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
<br>
<br>
<a href="index.html">Click to return to homepage</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I would to like search by things such as first name, email and city so for example if I have an entry with the name John and I type J into the first name search bar John and his other information would show in the table as well as anyone else with J in their name. 
Also the same thing for something such as city, if I type auck then all the entries with auck in the city section would show as well as the other information.

I'm unsure of how I would do this, I've managed to work out how to search for first name using `$search = $_GET['search'];` and then using:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($search=="")
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['speciality'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['streetname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['suburb'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['postcode'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
else if($row['firstname']==$search)
{
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['speciality'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['streetname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['suburb'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['postcode'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

I can do the same thing for last name and any other field but it makes the code very messy and I don't think it's the most efficient way of doing things.

If someone could please point me in the right direction on how to efficiently make a search function I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should be using your search variables to build your MySQL statement, not after the fact.  SELECT * FROM specialisttable WHERE firstname = '$firstnamesearchvariable'.  Etc.  Use LIKE and % wildcards if you don't want to have to be exact on the search.  SELECT * FROM specialisttable WHERE firstname LIKE '%$firstnamesearchvariable%' will return any firstname with $firstnamesearchvariable anywhere in it.

Comment: SELECT*FROM: Put some space in there.

Comment: Thank you for the help Andrew however I'm not entirely sure how to use LIKE and wildcards in my code could you please be a little bit more specific. Thank you for the help anyway.